# Make file with if else condition inside the for loop

Tags: makefile, sh

I am trying to loop using "for" inside the directory (dir) and building a go code and then checking with if dir name is equal to dir/task1 or dir/task2, is yes the zip the resource/ directory along with bootstrap else zip only bootstrap.

When I do make build, I see it is not going to else condition, please help

```
build:
    for directory in $$(find dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d) ; \
        do env GOOS=linux go build -ldflags="-s -w" -o "bootstrap" $${directory}/main.go ; \
            if [ $${directory}='dir/task1' ] || [ $${directory}='dir/task2' ]; then \
                zip -r $${directory}.zip bootstrap resources/ ; \
            else \
                zip $${directory}.zip bootstrap ; \
            fi \
        done
```

Comment: So you put `echo $${directory}` just above the `if` statement, and for some directories it prints strings which ostensibly _have to_ trigger executing of the `else` clause, right?

Comment: Consider creating two targets per directory for build step and zip invocation, respectively. A modular Makefile will be easier to maintain and save you time by not rebuilding the same stuff over again.

Comment: The error here is that you must use whitespace around operators in shell test clauses.  You cannot use `[ $${directory}='dir/task1' ]` because this is parsed by the shell as three words: `[`, `${directory}='dir/task1'`, and `]`, and the second word is just considered a word like `foo` or `bar`.  You must add whitespace around the operators like this: `[ $${directory} = 'dir/task1' ]` so that the shell parses it as 5 words: `[`, `${directory}`, `=`, `'dir/task1'`, and `]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `||` in the `if` clause is a [bashism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Portability) — that is, it will fail for many Unix shells other than GNU Bash. Also, it worth explicitly passing `-print` to `find` as not all implementations of it default to printing when no explicit action was specified in the call.

With these two fixed, the thing appears to work for me:

```
$ cat Makefile 
all:
    for directory in $$(find dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print); do \
        echo $${directory}; \
        if [ $${directory} = 'dir/task1' -o $${directory} = 'dir/task2' ]; then \
            echo "\tif branch"; \
        else \
            echo "\telse branch"; \
        fi; \
    done

$ mkdir -p dir/{task1,task2,task3,task4}
$ make --trace all
Makefile:2: target 'all' does not exist
for directory in $(find dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print); do \
    echo ${directory}; \
    if [ ${directory} = 'dir/task1' -o ${directory} = 'dir/task2' ]; then \
        echo "\tif branch"; \
    else \
        echo "\telse branch"; \
    fi; \
done
dir/task1
    if branch
dir/task3
    else branch
dir/task4
    else branch
dir/task2
    if branch
$
```

Comment: It is definitely not the case that `||` in an `if` clause is only valid in bash.  In POSIX sh the conditional of an if-statement is a command and a command can certainly contain `||` in POSIX sh: running `true || false` is perfectly legal POSIX sh.

Comment: The reason this version works while the original didn't is not the conversion of `||` to `-o`, it's the addition of whitespace around the `=` operator; see my comment on the question.